# Matlab cellstr length limit

Tags: matlab

I am using cellstr in Matlab to convert characters to cell string array. For example:

```
A = 'a1a2a3a4...a100'; % I do not list all of the characters in A
B = cellstr(A);
```

But the result is

```
B = 'a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9a10a11a12a13a14a15a16a17a18a19a20a21a22a23a24a25a26a27a28a29a30a31a32a33a34a35a36a37a38a39a40a41a42a43a...'
```

It does not convert all the characters. I guess it is caused by the limit. Does anyone know how to increase this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does convert all of the characters. The ellipsis comes from Matlab truncating the output of a cell array display at the width of your command window.
You can display the full contents of the cell array using `B{1}`:

```
>> A = sprintf('a%g',1:100);
>> B = cellstr(A)
B = 
    'a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9a10a11a12a13a14a15a16a17a18a19a20a21a22a23a24a25a26a...'
>> B{1}
ans =
a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9a10a11a12a13a14a15a16a17a18a19a20a21a22a23a24a25a26a27a28a29a30a31a32a33a34a35a36a37a38a39a40a41a42a43a44a45a46a47a48a49a50a51a52a53a54a55a56a57a58a59a60a61a62a63a64a65a66a67a68a69a70a71a72a73a74a75a76a77a78a79a80a81a82a83a84a85a86a87a88a89a90a91a92a93a94a95a96a97a98a99a100
```

This is the default format for cell-strings such that as many elements of the array can be displayed in the command window at one time in limited space:

```
>> [B,B]
ans = 
    'a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9a10a11a12a1...'    'a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9a10a11a12a1...'
>> [B,B,B]
ans = 
    'a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8...'    'a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8...'    'a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8...'
```

But, all of the string is contained within the cell array element itself.  The only limit to the size is the amount of memory Matlab has to create the array.